# Am trying to validate an xml schema file but is given me an error

Tags: xml, xsd

I am using eclipse to edit and XML schema file. I have two files, file one and file two.
file one seems to be ok but because file two is referencing file two (foreign key), I  have this error. Though it can be seen from the code that file one has `namespace`. I need some help.

```
src-resolve.4.1: Error resolving component 'pk_Top_200_Queries2'.
It was detected that 'pk_Top_200_Queries2' has no namespace, 
but components with no target namespace are not referenceable 
from schema document 
'file:///C:/java/workspace2/HomeWork2/Clicked_and_pos_12.xsd'. 
If 'pk_Top_200_Queries2' is intended to have a namespace, perhaps 
a prefix needs to be provided. If it is 
intended that 'pk_Top_200_Queries2' has no namespace, then 
an 'import' without a "namespace" attribute should be added to 
'file:///C:/java/workspace2/HomeWork2/Clicked_and_pos_12.xsd'.
```

**file 1: name =Top_200_Queries2 and the schema is below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Top_200_Queries2"
xmlns="http://www.example.org/Top_200_Queries2"
elementFormDefault="qualified">


<xsd:element name="T200Q">

<xsd:complexType>

<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="t200q"  maxOccurs="200">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>

<xsd:element name="qid" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element name="query" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element name="count" type="xsd:integer" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:key name="pk_qid">

<xsd:selector xpath=".//t200q" />
<xsd:field xpath="qid" />
</xsd:key>

</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

fiel 2 name= Clicked2.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Clicked2"
xmlns="http://www.example.org/Clicked2" elementFormDefault="qualified">



<xsd:element name = "Clicked2">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name = "clicks" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="qid" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="uid" type="xsd:integer"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:key name="pk_Clicked2">
<xsd:selector xpath=".//clicks"/>
<xsd:field xpath="qid"/>
<xsd:field xpath="uid"/>
</xsd:key>
<xsd:keyref name="fk_contains_query" refer="pk_Top_200_Queries2">
<xsd:selector xpath=".//clicks"/>
<xsd:field xpath="qid"/>
</xsd:keyref>

<xsd:keyref name="fk_contains_url" refer="pk_URL">
<xsd:selector xpath=".//clicks"/>
<xsd:field xpath="uid"/>
</xsd:keyref>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

both files are in the same package in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You provide two documents whose names, you say, are `Top_200_Queries2` and `Clicked2.xsd`.  They look OK, at first glance.

The error message you quote does not mention either of these file names but instead mentions files called `pk_Top_200_Queries2` and `Clicked_and_pos_12.xsd`.  So the first question to ask is:  is the processor actually reading the files you want it to read, or is it reading some other schema documents?